# Error when using TypeConverter with Room: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, moshi

**I get this error:**

> error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can
> consider adding a type converter for it.
> private final java.util.List<com.example.Detail.Stat> stats = null;

I can't figure it out. I have Added the typeconverter to the database, but still get this error. Any ideas what I do wrong?

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
data class Detail(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val stats: List<Stat>,
    val types: List<String>

){
    data class Stat(
        val baseStat: Int,
        val stat: String
    )
}
```

**Typeconverter:**

```
@ProvidedTypeConverter
class StatConverter @Inject constructor(
    private val moshi: Moshi
){
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromJson(value: String): List<Detail.Stat>? {
        val listType = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, Detail.Stat::class.java)
        val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<Detail.Stat>> = moshi.adapter(listType)
        return adapter.fromJson(value)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toJson(type: List<Detail.Stat>?): String {
        val listType = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, Detail.Stat::class.java)
        val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<Detail.Stat>> = moshi.adapter(listType)
        return adapter.toJson(type)
    }
}
```

**Database:**

```
@Database(entities = [Detail::class], version = 1, exportSchema = true)
@TypeConverters(StatConverter::class)
abstract class Database : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun detailDao(): DetailDao

    companion object{
        const val DATABASE = "database"
    }

}
```

**DI module where room is provided:**

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppDatabase(
        application: Application,
        statConverter: StatConverter
    ): Database {
        return Room
            .databaseBuilder(application, Database::class.java,
                Database.DATABASE
            )
            .addTypeConverter(statConverter)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    }
```

**EDIT:**

The typeconverter code works fine with the other field (List) in the entity, but not with List.

Comment: Try moving `Stat` out to be a top-level class, not nested inside of `Detail`, and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare That seem to be working. I guess that means it can't find a nested class inside the entity being converted. Thanks for the comment, could you type it as an answer so I could reward you the bounty thanks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, something about your nested `data class` is causing problems, and so moving `Stat` out from being nested in `Detail` helped.

If you have the time, you might try creating a scrap project that illustrates the problem, then file an issue on [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:413107&s=created_time:desc), attaching that project as a demonstration of the problem. I don't see anything that quite matches, but there are a lot of issues, so perhaps I missed it.

Comment: I will open the issue as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't run your code or test this out, but from eyeballing it here, is it possible it's the difference between nullable `List<Detail.Stat>?` in the type converter and non-nullable `List<Stat>` in the entity? Either make entity nullable or type-converter non-nullable and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried both and it still yielded the same error.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but using the exact same code for the type conveter for the field List<String> works fine, but not with List<Stat>